# macOS shortcut/bash script to immediately close (UNIX signal 9/SIGKILL) all "Not Responding" programs

Tags: macos

I'd like a shortcut or tool that sends UNIX signal 9/SIGKILL to all **Not Responding** programs.

A clickable shortcut is preferred, although I'm also willing to set up a Bash script and run that from command line.

Comment: how would you see all not responding apps

Comment: That's actually significantly more tricky than it looks. Finder's notion of "not responding" is different from the process state on Unix process level, an application can consist of several processes, etc. Looking forward to see an answer which takes all of that into account.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Applescript I used on Maverics...

It basically looks for 'Not Responding' apps in Activity Monitor and Kills them

```
tell application "Activity Monitor" to run  --We need to run Activity Monitor
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Activity Monitor"
     tell radio button 1 of radio group 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 to click --Using the CPU View 
     tell outline 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 -- working with the list 
         set notResponding to rows whose value of first static text contains "Not Responding" -- Looking for Not responding process
         repeat with aProcess in notResponding
             set pid to value of text field 5 of aProcess  -- For each non responding process retrieve the PID 
             if pid is not "" then do shell script ("kill -9 " & pid) -- KILL the PID. 
         end repeat
     end tell
end tell
```